# Recebendo dados no Controller

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Estou tentando desenvolver um MVC do zero, sem frameworks, porém estou tendo dificuldades na forma de receber os valores inputados via form em meu controlller, gostaria de uma ajuda neste sentido.

O meu formulário está da seguinte forma

**CadastraUsuario.php**

```
<form action="controller/UsuarioController.php?method=addUser" method="post" >
<div class="card" style="top:40px">
    <div class="card-header">
        <span class="card-title">Profissional</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-right">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" name="nome" id="nome" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-right">Login:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" name="login" id="login" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-right">Senha:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control col-sm-6" name="senha" id="senha" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-right">Data de Nascimento:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control col-sm-6" name="data_nasc" id="data_nasc" value="" />
    </div>            
    <div class="card-footer">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="" />
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset">Limpar</button>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="index.php">Cancelar</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UsuarioController.php**

```
class UsuarioController {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
public function addUser($nome){
    echo $nome;
    }
}
```

Tentei de várias formas e não consegui. Queria saber passando como parametro o method addUser, como utilizar a variável no controller.

Comment: Uma das poucas vantagens de usar o MVC é pegar um *framework* pronto. Eu também não gosto de *frameworks*, mas já que vou fazer na mão eu faço de uma forma mais simples que MVC, ainda mais em PHP que é uma linguagem de *script* que é propícia para isto. De qualquer forma a pergunta não é boa. Dizer que fez algumas coisas e que não estão conseguindo ir pra frente e agora que delegar a solução para outra pessoa me parece fora de escopo. Não fechei porque está em linha tênue já que pelo menos começou fazer algo,mas na prática não tem um problema específico ainda, então pode ser amplo ou não claro

Comment: Fazer o `action` do formulário como `action="controller/UsuarioController.php?method=addUser"` não fará com que seja executado o método `addUser` do seu *Controller*. Nada é mágico. Você precisará tratar a requisição em algum lugar específico, receber essas informações e fazer as devidas chamadas à classe e método. Fora isso, sua classe `UsuarioController` não fez muito sentido. Recomendo que atenha-se mais ao básico, não só do PHP como principalmente dos conceitos web, antes de tentar construir um *framework* próprio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ao que parece sua função `addUser` não é chamada, assim como a classe `UsuarioController` também não é instanciada. Tente mudar seu código para:

**CadastraUsuario.php**

```html
<form action="controller/UsuarioController.php" method="post" >
```

**UsuarioController.php**

```php
class UsuarioController{
    public function addUser($nome){
        echo $nome;
    }
}

$classeUsuarioController = new UsuarioController(); // instancia sua classe

if(isset($_POST['nome'])){ // Quando existir o post nome:
    $classeUsuarioController->addUser($_POST['nome']);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Comment: Talvez não tenha conseguido expressar direito meu questionamento, mas é exatamente isso que queria, muito obrigado.